# PATH environment variable behaviour when switching user with and without login

Tags: bash, environment-variables, bashrc, .profile, environment

when i login as a user then switch to another one, the `PATH` environment variable changes when the switch is done with and without login. see the following snippet

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/ubuntu.pem ubuntu@127.0.0.1
ubuntu@kingdom:~$ echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | grep sbin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
ubuntu@kingdom:~$ sudo su -l foo # with login
foo@kingdom:~$ echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | grep sbin
foo@kingdom:~$ exit
logout
ubuntu@kingdom:~$ sudo su foo # without login
foo@kingdom:/home/ubuntu$ echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | grep sbin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
foo@kingdom:/home/ubuntu$ exit
exit

$ ssh -o -i ~/.ssh/foo.pem foo@127.0.0.1
foo@kingdom:~$ echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | grep sbin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
foo@kingdom:~$ sudo su -l ubuntu
ubuntu@kingdom:~$ echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | grep sbin
ubuntu@kingdom:~$
```

as you can see, when i login into the ubuntu box using `ubuntu` user and check the user `PATH`, the `/sbin` is there. when i switch to `foo` user, and check the `PATH`, it is affected depending whether `-l` (for login) was specified when the switch is made. if a login is made, the `PATH` is affected and the `/sbin` is not there. while it does not happen when the a login is skipped when the user is switched.

if you connect as `foo` user to the ubuntu box, the `PATH` holds `/sbin`. if i switch to `ubuntu` user, then check the `PATH`, the `/sbin` is not there if i switched to `ubuntu` user with a login.

by the way, i am using bash.

i also tried to delete some of the user bash and profile configuration, but it did not help. see below

```
ubuntu@kingdom:~$ echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | grep sbin
ubuntu@kingdom:~$ sudo rm /home/foo/.bash /home/foo/.bashrc /home/foo/.profile
ubuntu@kingdom:~$ sudo su -l foo
foo@kingdom:~$ echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | grep sbin
foo@kingdom:~$ exit
logout
ubuntu@kingdom:~$ sudo rm -rf /etc/profile.d/
ubuntu@kingdom:~$ sudo su -l foo
foo@kingdom:~$ echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | grep sbin
foo@kingdom:~$ exit
logout
ubuntu@kingdom:~$ cat /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

**UPDATE (TL;DR):**

```
ubuntu@kingdom:~$ echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | grep sbin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
ubuntu@kingdom:~$ sudo su ubuntu
ubuntu@kingdom:~$ echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | grep sbin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
ubuntu@kingdom:~$ exit
exit
ubuntu@kingdom:~$ sudo su -l ubuntu
ubuntu@kingdom:~$ echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | grep sbin
ubuntu@kingdom:~$ exit
logout
```

**UPDATE 2:**

in the comments, one mentioned to print the `PATH` values. so for each file in the read chain, i added in the first and last line of each file the print of the `PATH`. now i am more confused. see the snippet below

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/ubuntu.pem ubuntu@127.0.0.1
/etc/profile: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
/etc/bash.bashrc: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
/etc/bash.bashrc: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
/etc/profile: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
/home/ubuntu/.profile: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
/home/ubuntu/.bashrc: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
/home/ubuntu/.bashrc: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
/home/ubuntu/.profile: /home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

ubuntu@kingdom:~$ sudo su -l ubuntu
/etc/profile: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
/etc/bash.bashrc: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
/etc/bash.bashrc: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
/etc/profile: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin
/home/ubuntu/.profile: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin
/home/ubuntu/.bashrc: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin
/home/ubuntu/.bashrc: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin
/home/ubuntu/.profile: /home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin
ubuntu@kingdom:~$ exit
logout

ubuntu@kingdom:~$ sudo su ubuntu
/etc/bash.bashrc: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
/etc/bash.bashrc: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
/home/ubuntu/.bashrc: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
/home/ubuntu/.bashrc: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

1. why it behaves like so?
2. how can debug it and make sure the `PATH` will holds the `/sbin` when switching to the user with a login?

Comment: I don't get this `if a login is made, the PATH is affected and the /sbin is not there. while it does not happen when the a login is skipped when the user is switched.`... If I get you correctly path `/sbin` is seen when you do `su -l` but not when you do `su` alone without `-l`?

Comment: assuming your shell is `bash`: did you read `man bash`? It contains a section that describes in depth which config files are read when. That should allow you to reconstruct which config file is setting which path. Also: you can do a `echo "this is ~/.bashrc, PATH is $PATH"` in each config file to debug this.

Comment: @George: i included a snippet in case my explanation is unclear and if i understood your question, you are mistaken -- the opposite is correct. that is, with `-l` the `/sbin` goes out of the `PATH`

Comment: @TomášPospíšek: i already read the documentation before i turned to post my question. even tried `strace` to understand which files changes the `PATH`.

Comment: Ok I see. What is contained in `~/.bash_profile`, and `~/.profile` for both users?

Comment: @TomášPospíšek: updated my original post to hold the output of the `PATH`

Comment: @George: the switching of the user does not necessary involves two different user. note that it  happens even if a login is made to the same user.

Comment: Hi @MrRoth, the "debug" results are interesting. The essential insight coming out from the results is, I think, the fact that `$PATH` gets set differently even *before* any config files are read. Why this? To find out you will need to study how `su`, `sudo` and `ssh` set up the user environment. I think one crucial element in all of this is `man pam`. I _think_ that each of the command above intertwines with `pam` at some point. To myself `pam` and the interplay of `su`, `sudo`, `ssh` and `login` is a bit of a mystery too...

Comment: @TomášPospíšek: thank you. i will keep checking it.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at `man bash` the  `-l` option determines what config file is read:

```
INVOCATION
   A login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is a -, or one started with the --login option.

   An interactive shell is one started without non-option arguments and without the -c option whose standard input and error are both connected to  ter‐
   minals (as determined by isatty(3)), or one started with the -i option.  PS1 is set and $- includes i if bash is interactive, allowing a shell script
   or a startup file to test this state.

   The following paragraphs describe how bash executes its startup files.  If any of the files exist but cannot be read, bash reports an error.   Tildes
   are expanded in filenames as described below under Tilde Expansion in the EXPANSION section.

   When  bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from
   the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.  After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and
   reads  and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.  The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit
   this behavior.

   When a login shell exits, bash reads and executes commands from the file ~/.bash_logout, if it exists.

   When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc, if these  files
   exist.  This may be inhibited by using the --norc option.  The --rcfile file option will force bash to read and execute commands from file instead of
   /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc.

   When bash is started non-interactively, to run a shell script, for example, it looks for the variable BASH_ENV in the environment, expands its  value
   if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as the name of a file to read and execute.  Bash behaves as if the following command were executed:
          if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi
   but the value of the PATH variable is not used to search for the filename.

   If  bash is invoked with the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of sh as closely as possible, while conforming to
   the POSIX standard as well.  When invoked as an interactive login shell, or a non-interactive shell with the --login option,  it  first  attempts  to
   read  and  execute  commands  from  /etc/profile  and  ~/.profile, in that order.  The --noprofile option may be used to inhibit this behavior.  When
   invoked as an interactive shell with the name sh, bash looks for the variable ENV, expands its value if it is defined, and uses the expanded value as
   the  name of a file to read and execute.  Since a shell invoked as sh does not attempt to read and execute commands from any other startup files, the
   --rcfile option has no effect.  A non-interactive shell invoked with the name sh does not attempt to read any other startup files.  When  invoked  as
   sh, bash enters posix mode after the startup files are read.

   When bash is started in posix mode, as with the --posix command line option, it follows the POSIX standard for startup files.  In this mode, interac‐
   tive shells expand the ENV variable and commands are read and executed from the file whose name is the expanded value.  No other  startup  files  are
   read.

   Bash  attempts to determine when it is being run with its standard input connected to a network connection, as when executed by the remote shell dae‐
   mon, usually rshd, or the secure shell daemon sshd.  If bash determines it is being run  in  this  fashion,  it  reads  and  executes  commands  from
   ~/.bashrc and ~/.bashrc, if these files exist and are readable.  It will not do this if invoked as sh.  The --norc option may be used to inhibit this
   behavior, and the --rcfile option may be used to force another file to be read, but neither rshd nor sshd  generally  invoke  the  shell  with  those
   options or allow them to be specified.

   If the shell is started with the effective user (group) id not equal to the real user (group) id, and the -p option is not supplied, no startup files
   are read, shell functions are not inherited from the environment, the SHELLOPTS, BASHOPTS, CDPATH, and GLOBIGNORE variables, if they  appear  in  the
   environment,  are ignored, and the effective user id is set to the real user id.  If the -p option is supplied at invocation, the startup behavior is
   the same, but the effective user id is not reset.
```

The two paragraphs that answer your question are:

> When  bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from
>          the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.  After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and
>          reads  and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.  The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit
>          this behavior.
>
> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc, if these  files
>          exist.  This may be inhibited by using the --norc option.  The --rcfile file option will force bash to read and execute commands from file instead of
>          /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc.

Comment: thank you for the reply. i've added the output of the `PATH` in each of the files. please see my update on the original post.